# Questions about java applet signing

Tags: java, ssl, applet

On my website, I use a java applet, I don't want my website's users have to add my website's url to the Java's whitelist to use it so I have to sign it with a certificate from a trusted authority.

I have some questions about applet signing : the applet I want to sign is already signed by another certificate, but it has expired.

Can I sign the applet directly ? Or do I have to "un-sign" it first ? If so,   how do I do that ?

I have an other java applet that I would like to sign, if I buy a code signing from Thawte ([link](https://www.rapidsslonline.com/ssl-brands/thawte/code-signing.aspx)) from example, can I sign my two applets with it, or do I have to buy from Thawte two times ? (I think that I can sign multiple applets with it, but I'd like to be sure)

Comment: a code signing certificate is bound to the company/person not the code so you can use it on any applets you want. anyway with the huge amouts of bugs in the java plugins in the last years they are very often disabled in the browsers so most users will still not see them.

Comment: Yes I know that java's applet are bound to disappear, Google Chrome doesn't support them anymore since 09/2015 and Firefox won't either by the end of 2016. But in the meantime I have to make the warning "This applet isn't signed, do you really want to execute it ?" that appears each time an user accesses the page disappear

Comment: yes you can sign them. and its easy to remove a signature and sign it new. but basically that will tell the browser and also user you guarantee for the code (that it contains no exploits, big bugs...) so i am not sure if i would do this for code i did not write myself.